# How to specify the parameter for FeatureUnion to let it pass to underlying transformer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

In my code, I am trying to access the `sample_weight` of the `StandardScaler`. However, this `StandardScaler` is within a `Pipeline` which again is within a `FeatureUnion`. I can't seem to get this parameter name correct: `scaler_pipeline__scaler__sample_weight` which should be specified in the `fit` method of the preprocessor object.

I get the following error: `KeyError: 'scaler_pipeline`

What should this parameter name be? Alternatively, if there is a generally better way to do this, feel free to propose it.

The code below is a standalone example.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd

class ColumnSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """Select only specified columns."""

    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.columns]

    def set_output(self, *, transform=None):
        return self

df = pd.DataFrame({'ds':[1,2,3,4],'y':[1,2,3,4],'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,2,3,4],'c':[1,2,3,4]})
sample_weight=[0,1,1,1]

scaler_pipeline = Pipeline(
    [
        (
            "selector",
            ColumnSelector(['a','b']),
        ),
        ("scaler", StandardScaler()),
    ]
)

remaining_pipeline = Pipeline([("selector", ColumnSelector(["ds","y"]))])

# Featureunion fitting training data
preprocessor = FeatureUnion(
    transformer_list=[
        ("scaler_pipeline", scaler_pipeline),
        ("remaining_pipeline", remaining_pipeline),
    ]
).set_output(transform="pandas")

df_training_transformed = preprocessor.fit_transform(
    df, scaler_pipeline__scaler__sample_weight=sample_weight
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fit_transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit_transform) has no parameter called `scaler_pipeline__scaler__sample_weight`.

Instead, it is expecting to receive *"parameters passed to the fit method of each step"* as a dict of string, *"where each parameter name is prefixed such that parameter p for step s has key s__p"*.

So, in your example, it should be:

```py
df_training_transformed = preprocessor.fit_transform(
    df, {"scaler_pipeline__scaler__sample_weight":sample_weight}
)
```